# AUC estimated by leave-one-out cross validation (LOOCV); how to estimate confidence interval for it?

Tags: confidence-interval, cross-validation, auc

I use logistic regression with a set of predictors X and a binary dependent variable y. I use LOOCV to produce "out-of-sample" model predictions y^_i for each x_i, where the model is estimated without (x_i, y_i). I use y^ and y to produce an ROC-curve and calculate the area under it (the AUC). I believe this is the preferred method for estimating an unbiased AUC of a predictive model. (If the LOOCV was used to choose the predictor set I know it's not perfectly unbiased, but let's disregard that for now.)

My question is: How do I create a valid confidence interval for my LOOCV-based AUC estimate?

- An AUC may be interpreted as the probability that my model orders a random positive and negative case pair correctly. Does this mean that the naiive approach of AUC +- 1.96 * sqrt(AUC*(1-AUC)/n) is meaningful?
- Should I run a bootstrap procedure on top of it all? (I.e. generate a sequence of resampled data sets with replacement, run the LOOCV procedure to produce an AUC for each data set, order the AUCs and use the 0.025 and 0.975 tails)?
- Something else?

Comment: I won't give you an answer since I only know what the problems are, and that is that for CV samples are dependent, so it's hard to get valid confidence intervals, if it was on an independent test than that would be easy. Also, whatever CI you get if for the CV results and not for the results of a model fitted on the whole dataset. Also see https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2019.1672556 and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/cross-validation-confidence-intervals-for-test-error/ which might contain an answer.

Comment: bootstrap will work, but you have to run CV in each bootstrap sample and not just bootstrap the results. You can also just wing it and calculate CI as if it was from an independent dataset but keep in mind that that CI is biased

Comment: I gave you the wrong link, ignore the first one, this is the paper meant  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4533123/

Comment: Thanks, and a great reference! 
Yes, I run the bootstrap as a for-loop wrapped around the whole thing. By "just winging it", did you mean my very naiive approach of simply treating the AUC as a probability, with sd = sqrt(AUC*(1-AUC)), and adding this times 1.96/sqrt(n) on both sides?

Comment: No, there is a special formula for confidence intervals for AUC (not taking in account CV dependence) I don't have a reference on hand, you will have to find it yourself. Your naive approach would not work, because it matters how many subjects you have in each group not just in total. Also, AUC is proportion of pairs of datapoints, not proportion of datapoints, so there is that complication as well.